# WPF, WCF, and Entity Framework for Enterprise App Architecture

Tags: .net, wpf, wcf, entity-framework, soa

We are working on changing an old project to a new technology. We decided to use EF + WCF + WPF with a SOA aproach.

After some research we decided to use the following architecture:

- EF for the database operations (CRUD) - on the server
- DTO for data transport (here we have 2 mappings: DTO-EF & EF-DTO).
- the business objects will be on the client - classes implementing the WPF interfaces(IEditableObject, INotifyPropertyChanged, etc) (here we put again two mapping transforms - DTO-BO & BO-DTO)
- the validation will be part on the client side, part on the server.

Can someone tell me if this is a correct aproach for a average size enterprise app and if not what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Two comments:

- Having both DTO and BO seems unnecessary, you can make DTOs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and cut out the middle man. You will also create ViewModel classes on top of these, it will become quite unmanageable soon. It is also prone for mapping errors.
- You haven't mentioned about using any mapping libraries for DTO<->EF copy. Consider using AutoMapper or ValueInjecter.

Comment: I'm using Automaper. What do you mean by using DTO as BO? Put them in a project and referencing them in both server side and client? Also i do not know exactly how to build the ViewModels on top of the DTO. Can you give me an example, a link maybe where i can see how to do it correctly? THANKS for your answer.

Comment: 1)You are going to return these DTOs in service methods or take as parameters they will be available by default at client side from service proxies.2) For every view on client side there will be ViewModels that has properties that exposes these DTOs to the view and has commands to act on it. Lets say you have a customers add/remove screen, you will create ObservableCollection<CustomerDTO> in EditCustomersViewModel and bind to a grid to allow for add/edit.

Comment: 1) If you extend the DTOs on the service, the interface implementations will not pass through the service reference.2) What if you want a more generic aproach...let's say a generic window for editing some tables (entities). I mean if you have 100 tables in your database and you need a 1 on 1 window for editing those tables (entities)... it would be preferable a generic aproach (autogenerate window with list/detail controls) over building one window (view) foreach table.

Comment: Keep the DTOs to have just data and INotifyPropertyChanged; move your business logic to a layer on top of EF separate from DTO. I am not sure about your application but even for your example you need only one view and view model that changes the underlying source collection based on what table has been selected.